# How do I access an external IP on Android?

Tags: android, ip, polymer, browser-sync

I would like to access my webserver running a [Polymer starter kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/) app from an Android devices, but I don't seem to get it to work..

Polymer starter kit comes with [browser-sync](http://www.browsersync.io/), which is very nice, but

I cán access my webapp on another laptop, but when I try to access it from an Android device it just keeps loading and eventually there will be a connection timeout. I triend another android device, but still the same.

Any Idea's how to access the app(external ip) from android?

Answer (score 1):

Is this only for development/debugging purposes or do you want to deploy in such a scenario?

For debugging you can use Chrome's remote-debugging capabilities https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging. 
I haven't tried but I think the ADB tool allows to redirect TCP connections as well.

Otherwise you need to teach Android the IP routes (and optionally a DNS) so the device can route connection attempts to your server.